# Visual Studio C# editor context action to change autoproperty to property body with SetValue(ref _field, value)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, resharper, inotifypropertychanged

[image: Currently I have this]

This is what I have in context action menu in C# editor now.

However, **previously I had** also an option to change the auto-property into the property with backing field and set body, which contains `SetProperty(ref _myField, value);`, which is super handy when working with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (in MvvM pattern).

Having it previously I never paid attention what tool/extension provides it, as I am considering that this is not Visual Studio native feature.

I've recently upgraded VS to 15.7 and apparently something has changed in my configuration or ... (again, I don't know who was providing that super thing)!

I am using *Resharper*, what might had been its feature, but I am still not sure.
I was also mostly using it withing Xamarin/MvvmCross projects, so that might be also something related (an I've recently upgraded to last versions of those as well).

So, is there anyone who might know **what tool makes this feature available**?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found an explanation.
This is probably because of newer version of Resharper, but this option currently is called `To property with change notification`.

And it gets available after the class you are defining the property in has a member-method annotated with `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` attribute which tells Resharper that this is the one who cares for the value changes in implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.

[image]